# JBPM Community or Enterprise Edition for Real time projects

Tags: jbpm

In real-time projects, which version of jbpm would be used? Community or Enterprise version?

Development would be based on Eclipse or Business Central? Please guide on which Eclipse version, which versions of jbpm plugins should be used?

Answer (score 0):

Both jBPM versions(community and enterprise) are same. The only difference is, in enterprise JBPM version you will get additional benefits from Red Hat. Go through [link](https://www.redhat.com/en/about/value-of-subscription) for more details.

For development, you should use VSCode. Eclipse and its plugins are no longer supported.